# I dont create android webview error refresh the page

Tags: asp.net, webview

I created android web-view http://www.matematikistan.net/android.

When I take a picture and start an ASP.NET file upload, web-view refreshes page and does not set photo value in file upload in return to `default2.aspx`.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: [webview manifest][1]


[showwebview.java][2]


[sorusor.aspx][3]


  [1]: http://matematikistan.net/1.png
  [2]: http://matematikistan.net/2.png
  [3]: http://matematikistan.net/3.png